# Blazor WebAssembly Page with no layout

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have a layout setup in a Blazor Web Assembly app (the standard way in App.razor).

I can set a different layout for 1 page by using this line at the top of the .razor file:

```
@layout NewLayoutName
```

However, how can I tell a page to use no layout at all?

I've googled this and can find nothing. I've tried the following and it also doesn't work:

```
@layout null
@layout ""
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No can do.

You'll need to either remove DefaultLayout attribute from RouteView in App.razor and specify your preferred layout in each page (which is what I do).

Alternatively, leave the default layout as is, but create a 'Null Layout':

**NullLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@Body
```

then use:

```
@layout NullLayout
```

in pages where you don't want the default layout.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I've done.